# Can't Copy Paste Mirrored Pose

Tags: animation, rigging

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp_SqjB0468#t=19m38s) but when I reach this part part at 19:38 I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it copies but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> nothing happens.

A little menu appears on the side with *Flipped on X-Axis* selected but the right side doesn't copy the left side.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: i prssed crtl c here]

[image: crtl shift v but didnt work]

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5329" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5329/)

Comment: i added to the post @moonboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform any kind of mirroring operation on your bones the names on the left and right side of your rig must have identical names, other than the L/R indication. All the bones on the right side of your armature have '.001' at the end of the names left over from being copied at some point. Remove the .001 from each of the names on the right side so they match the left side and you will be able to paste the pose mirrored.

Comment: Thank you so much!! i renamed the right side and tried again and it worked. I couldn never imagine this was the problem! you sved me a lot of time!! thank yo.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Macklehatton, your bones have bad suffixes, they should end with ".r" (or "_r" or ".R" or "_R"...) if you want Blender to understand that you want to mirror. Your left bones are correctly named, so you should delete all your right bones, then select the left bones and go to *Armature* > *Symmetrized*. The new bones will automatically be called with the good suffixes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! i renamed the right side and tried again and it worked. I couldn never imagine this was the problem! you sved me a lot of time!! thank yo.

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize what symmetrize actually does. Looks like it only works if the existing bones already have an L or R in the name, which can be added to an unlabeled rig with AutoName Left/Right in the same menu. That was probably why I didn't understand what it does. I've been looking for this feature recently, thanks.

Comment: Yes, Symmetrize makes the process a bit simpler than before   ;)

Answer (score 0):

it happens to me too and I followed a good tutorial by [Sebastian Lague](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mZtc33rQ3c&ab_channel=SebastianLague)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time to answer the question. Could you add a little more information about the actual workflow ? It's better if you don't resort to linking an external video since it may not be always available in the future.